# How can I get this FCM/GCM response when sending a notification?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

When removing the last registration ID from a group, the notification_key that was used until now will be removed by Google.

For this reason, I want to know how many devices there are left in the group, so if the last device in the group signs out, I can remove the group from the database.

Since there is no 'get device count' functionality, I want to send a hidden notification (doesn't show up in the notification tray, gets ignored by app), and add the 'success' and 'failure' numbers.

However, I can't be sure whether any of the 'failures' are temporary, so I don't know whether to count them towards the device count.

So far, I haven't been able to reproduce this reply from FCM:

```
{
  "success":1,
  "failure":2,
  "failed_registration_ids":[
     "regId1",
     "regId2"
  ]
}
```

which they claim is supposedly possible: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group .

So... two questions: How can I reproduce that reply, and should I count the 'failures' towards my device count per group?

Things I've tried that didn't work:
1) Uninstalling the app one one device from the group
2) Shutting down one of the devices
3) Adding an invalid registration ID to the group (which doesn't work)

PS: FCM/GCM really needs to up their documentation/FAQ game.

Comment: Have you also considered storing the registration tokens associated to that notification key? :) I think it'll be easier to store it for yourself, to use the details (in your case, the number of devices) later on. You will have to do the adding and removing too, it's extra work. It's up to you if it's worth it or not. I'll be taking a look around too. I'm not sure, but I think there was something similar to this post before. I'll let you know. Cheers!

Comment: If there was, I'd appreciate a link; I haven't been able to find it. I don't want to store multiple registration tokens because I want a user to be able to be logged in on multiple devices without me having to handle each one separately. For this reason, I store a notification_key and notification_name which contain all the registration ids a person has. On logout, the registration id is then removed from the group.